# Relational Database (Foreign Keys)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, foreign-key-relationship

I have a categories table in my app and I want all my questions to match the category the question is assigned to. The problem is I have four buttons for each category. Each question has a category_id which should reference from the categories table. The first question is good because it actually belongs to the music category, but when I press the TV category, it renders the second question which it belongs to the music category but it should render the third question from the questionnaires table which it suppose to belong to the TV category. This is a foreign key issue and I'm looking for a possible solution that may resolve it.

Questionnaire Migration

```
class CreateQuestionnaire < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :questionnaire do |t|
      t.string :question
      t.string :choices
      t.string :correct_answer
      t.integer :category_id 
      t.foreign_key :categories
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Category Table Seed

```
Category.create({name:'Music'})
Category.create({name:'TV'})
Category.create({name:'Movies'})
Category.create({name:'Games'})
```

Questionnaire Table Seed

```
Questionnaire.create({question: "In what year did MTV (Music Television) premiere and what was the first music video the channel aired?", choices:['1982 Michael Jackson Bille Jean', '1984 Madonna Like a virgin', '1981 The Buggles Video Killed The Radio Star'], correct_answer:"1981 The Buggles Video Killed The Radio Star", category_id:1 })
Questionnaire.create({question:"This game launched in 1991 on Sega Genesis which the player's mission is to collect as many golden rings as possible", choices:['Battletoads', 'Sonic The Hedgehog', 'Jewel Master'], correct_answer: "Sonic The Hedgehog", category_id:1})
Questionnaire.create({question: "This sitcom featured four girls living under one roof. They attended the same boarding school, ran a shop together and reside in a town called Peekskill." , choices:['Designing Women', 'The Facts of Life', 'Girlfriends'], correct_answer:'The Facts of Life', category_id: 2})
Questionnaire.create({question: "This martial arts film premiere in 1985 which featured a young man who studies Bruce Lee's techniques while on the search for his master. This was set in New York City." , choices:['The Last Dragon', 'The Karate Kid', 'Big Trouble in Little China'], correct_answer:'The Last Dragon', category_id: 3})
Questionnaire.create({question:"This game launched in 1991 on Sega Genesis which the player's mission is to collect as many golden rings as possible", choices:['Battletoads', 'Sonic The Hedgehog', 'Jewel Master'], correct_answer: "Sonic The Hedgehog", category_id:4})
```

Category Controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

before_action :require_player, only: [:index]

def index
    @categories=Category.all
    ###It shows a list of all the categories
    # binding.pry



    render :index
end

end
```

Category#Index

```
<h2>Categories </h2>



<% @categories.each do |category| %>
<form action = '/categories/<%=category.id %>/questionnaires/' method = 'GET'>

<ul>

<button type='submit' class="btn btn-default btn-block" style='vertical-align: middle; margin:0px;'><%=category.name%></button>

<br>
</ul>

</form>
<%end%>
```

Questionnaire Controller

```
class QuestionnairesController < ApplicationController

def index

    @question = Questionnaire.find(params[:category_id])
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @videos = VideoClue.find(params[:category_id])
    ###This finds all the questions from the question table by their category_id. Whenever I select a category, it matches the question related to the category

    render :show
    ###render :show Renders Html page
end
```

Questionnaire#Show

```
 <h1><%=@question.question%></h1>
```

Comment: you talkt about errors while rendering stuff. so where is your HTML?

Comment: It looks like the chat session you had with @huanson resolved the problem. Would you consider accepting the answer you have, then, by clicking the tick icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, tables are names plural. in your case: questionnaire**s**

since a `questionare belongs_to a category` and a `category has_many questionaires` you just go in the migration and go for

```
t.references :category
add_index :questionares, :category_id
```

then its just working fine with rails.

```
-@categories.each do |category|
  .category
    %h2=category.name
    -category.questions.each do |question|
      .question
        %h3=question.question
        -question.answers.each_with_index do |answer, index|
          %span.answer
            Number: ##{index}
            %br
             =answer.answer
```

---

btw: i would give you a slight better modelling

```
class Category
  has_many :questions

class Question
 has_many :answers
 has_one :correct_answer #save as correct_answer_id
 attr_accessor :given_answer_id
 def correct_answered?
   given_answer_id == correct_answer_id
 end

class Answer
  belongs_to :question
```

Comment: I have tried using t.references but it didn't work. The name of my model is Questionnaire and it contains a question, choices, correct_answer and category_id. So far my question still aren't matching up to their categories. What is with the category.each method? Where do I enter it?

Comment: in a controller you go @categories = Category.order("name asc") or stuff like that. 
the code i posted is working, definitely

Comment: When I select the TV category, it still shows the question with category_id:1.  It's suppose to show the next question that has category_id:2. I don't have a separate model for 'Answers'.

Comment: so on a click you are landing at /categories/1 and /categories/2 ?

Comment: so if it is categories/2 then inside the controller you go @questions = Category.find(params[:id]).questions and then you just go in your template [at]questions.each do |question| . that is working for sure - and your database is correct, for sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89437/discussion-between-michael-stokes-and-huan-son).